# Decoding extensible records in Elm

Tags: decode, elm

I have been using extensible records in elm (0.18).  My model contains these types:

```
type alias Cat c =
    { c
        | color : String
        , age : Int
        , name : String
        , breed : String
    }

type alias SimpleCat =
    Cat {}

type alias FeralCat =
    Cat
        { feral : Bool
        , spayed : Bool
        }
```

Now I want to be able to pass these types into a decoder.  I typically use the elm-decode-pipeline library `"NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline": "3.0.0 <= v < 4.0.0"`.

I set up this type:

```
catDecoder : Decode.Decoder SimpleCat
catDecoder = 
  Pipeline.decode SimpleCat
    |> Pipeline.required "color" Decode.string
    |> Pipeline.required "age" Decode.int
    |> Pipeline.required "name" Decode.string
    |> Pipeline.required "breed" Decode.string
```

But I get this error:

```
-- NAMING ERROR --------------------------------------------- ./src/Decoders.elm

Cannot find variable `SimpleCat`

141|     Pipeline.decode SimpleCat
```

This doesn't happen with my non-extensible types.  Is there any way to use these types with decoders?  (elm-decode-pipeline preferred, but I'd like to know if there is another way)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extensible records unfortunately do not currently (as of Elm 0.18) allow for creating them using their alias name as a constructor. You could instead write your own constructor function:

```elm
simpleCatConstructor : String -> Int -> String -> String -> SimpleCat
simpleCatConstructor color age name breed =
    { color = color, age = age, name = name, breed = breed }
```

Then you can substitute that in the call to `decode`:

```elm
catDecoder = 
    Pipeline.decode simpleCatConstructor
        |> Pipeline.required "color" Decode.string
        ...
```

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Assuming that I need decoders for all of these types, does that technique present any advantage over just making (somewhat redundant) non-extensible records?

Comment: If/Until Elm allows you to use types defined in the extensible fashion as constructors, you might be better off listing all properties on the definition of `FeralCat` since it still matches the `Cat a` alias